# C# to C code P/INvoke multiple std:string declarations lead to stack corruption

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, pinvoke

I built a c++ dll with external exports in order to call it from my C# program. The invokes work quite well for most of the functions ,but there comes a problem when I need to pass some strings from C# to C++.

I pass them as normal string and receive them as const char *. They are all fine and all the data is there,but then i go on to define a couple of strings from those char arrays .The code goes on without any problems until the I exit the function. Then it throws an exception saying,that the stack around the last defined std::string is corrupt, and I am really not sure why this is the case. I have tried lots of ways of defining the strings: copying them, changing the encoding from the P/Invoke definition.

Some extra info I am calling this function from a timer thread; I am mentioning this as I found, that some problems may occur with std::string on threads. This is done on a multi cpu  machine compiled in VS 2012 for x86.  Also attaching the relevant code below

```
#define OPENCV2P4

#include "openfabmap.hpp"
#include <fstream>
#ifdef OPENCV2P4
#include <opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp>
#endif


#include <stdio.h>

extern "C"
{

__declspec(dllexport) int   generateBOWImageDescs( const char* _dataPath,  const char* _bowImageDescPath,const char* _vocabPath ,int minWords)
{




 std::string dataPath(_dataPath);


  std::string bowImageDescPath( _bowImageDescPath);
  std::string vocabPath(_vocabPath);



cv::FileStorage fs; 

//ensure not overwriting training data
std::ifstream checker;
checker.open(bowImageDescPath.c_str());
if(checker.is_open()) { 

    checker.close();



    return -1;
}
 }
```

And the call from C#

```
 [DllImport(@"FabMap\FabMapCPP.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
         public static extern int generateBOWImageDescs( string _dataPath, string    _bowImageDescPath, string _vocabPath, int minWords);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also first question here, so any remarks on the wrong presentation of the question would be appreciated.

Edit:Ok fun fact the problem was with $cv::FileStorage fs; i removed it essentially and it started working ,might have been due to an improper allocation or something .

So this means the opencv file storage is causing the problem ,still not sure why.

Comment: Try to debug your application with AppVerifier. It will help you to determine place where stack corruption occurs

Comment: Is that available for Windows 7?

Comment: of course, it is a part of Windows SDK

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this 2 links:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311259

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b620dhe.aspx

Basically char* is IntPtr in C# and not string.

Comment: That is not correct, marshaling will properly convert a C# `string` to a `const char*`.

Comment: Ya it converts fine,but the thing is it corrupts the stack and later the heap in most cases ,which is weird.

Comment: @sixlettervariables - you are right, and Microsoft are wrong.

Comment: @Eden: you've confused managed C++'s use of System::String with marshaling via P/Invoke. I use `string` and `const char*` interchangeably every day with P/Invoke without issues. Artii's problem lies elsewhere.